# Outguess Mac Steganography

Tags: steganography

I'm trying to install the Steganography program , world famous, called Outguess.

I went to the website and donwloaded the version that I need, but after I extract the files from de ZIP, it gaves me a folder full of items, and right now I don't know how to run it, or install it.

I've tried the 'outguess' command on my Terminal and pops a message that command not found.

How do I install it, can you help me step-by-step, or there is a tutorial anywhere where I can solve this issue?

Thank you all , and sorry for my English, I'm not native English.

Regards, 
Ivan.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the issue.

I've run the ./compile, then 'make', then ./outguess and the command that I've wanted and the problem was solved.